# What is the best practice to use the clients in ballerina

Tags: client, ballerina

```
import ballerina/http;
import booksvc.googlebooks as gb;

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {
    resource function get books() returns gb:Book[]|http:InternalServerError {
        gb:Book[]|error books = gb:loadBooks();
        if books is error {
            return http:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        } 
        return books;
    }

    resource function get author(string bookname) returns string|http:InternalServerError {
        string|error name = gb:getAuthor(bookname);
        if name is error {
            return http:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have to use the OpenApi client for functions `loadbooks` and `getAuthor`. What is the best practice to initialize the client and use it in those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ballerina/http;
import booksvc.googlebooks as gb;

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {
    private final http:Client googleBooks;

    function init() returns error?{
        self.googleBooks = check new("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", {auth: {token: apiKey}});
    }

    resource function get books() returns gb:Book[]|http:InternalServerError {
        gb:Book[]|error books = gb:loadBooks(self.googleBooks);
        if books is error {
            return http:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        } 
        return books;
    }

    resource function get author(string bookname) returns string|http:InternalServerError {
        string|error name = gb:getAuthor(bookname, self.googleBooks);
        if name is error {
            return http:INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Maintain the client as private final variable at the service level and initialize it inside the service init function. Then pass that as parameter to `loadBooks` and `getAuthor` functions.